# Maven : Invalid element name : build

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am new to the maven tool. I am trying automation testing using maven in eclipse. As instructed by a YouTube video, I added a few dependencies in the pom.xml file. When I added the plugins under the build element, I am getting an error saying "Invalid element name : build".
The error says "*Multiple markers at this line

- Invalid element name:
- build
  One of the following is expected:
- dependency
  Error indicated by:
  {http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}
  with code:
- Malformed POM D:\Eclipse\Automation\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'build' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n\r\n... @23:8)*"

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ll.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Automation</name>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    
  
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please check the construction of the `pom.xml` here: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html you have opened a tag `<dependencies>` but not closed at the wrong position ... the tag `<dependencies>` contains the dependencies as implied by the name but does not contain the part `<build>...</build>`...

Comment: Thank you, it was a silly mistake that I noticed after your comment! It is resolved now!

Answer (score 1):

You put the *build* tag into the dependencies area. Close the tag *dependencies* after the last dependency.

```
...
<dependencies>
  ...
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  ...
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are multiple dependency tags in your POM file you need to add all of your dependency tags under the dependencies tag something like this

Before
[image: Before image]
Here in the first Image, you can see at line no 9 there is a red underline

After
[image: After image]
But when you add the dependencies tag its not there

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your answer and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.